# Xamarin ListView TwoWay binding doesn't work on iOS

Tags: android, ios, xaml, listview, xamarin

In our Xamarin application we have a ListView that shows a list of Surveys.If the user selects a Survey they will be taken to that surveys details page. To do that, we use `TwoWay` binding on the `SelectedItem` property, and add a setter to the SelectedItem property in the controller.

Xaml-

```
<ListView x:Name= "surveyList" ItemsSource= "{Binding Surveys}" SelectedItem= "{Binding SelectedSurvey, Mode=TwoWay}" BackgroundColor= "White" HorizontalOptions= "Fill" SeparatorColor= "Gray" RowHeight= "50" >
```

C#-

```
private SurveyListItem _selectedSurvey;
public SurveyListItem SelectedSurvey
{
    get { return _selectedSurvey; }
    set
    {
        _selectedSurvey = value;
        if (_selectedSurvey == null)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            return;
        }
        OnSurveySelected(_selectedSurvey);
        _selectedSurvey = null;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

This works find on `Android` but does not work on `iOS`. Tapping the item in the list does not set the `_selectedSurvey` or call the setter of `SelectedSurvey`.

I could make a quick fix and change this to some sort of tap gesture but we are using ListView in other places of the application where multi-select is needed, and changing all of that to tap gesture would be a pain.

Any ideas why this would work for `Android` but not `iOS`?

**Edit-**

Full Xaml-

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding= "utf-8" ?>

< TabbedPage xmlns = "http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"

             xmlns:x= "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"

              x:Class= "MyApp.View.ModuleContentPage"

             xmlns:vm= "clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModel;assembly=MyApp"

             xmlns:local= "clr-namespace:MyApp.View;assembly=MyApp"

             Title= "Module Content Render" >

  < TabbedPage.Children >

    < ContentPage Title= "Summary" IsEnabled= "False" >

      < ContentPage.Content >

        < StackLayout Padding= "20, 20, 20, 0" >

          < Label Text= "To Do: Render Module Content Here." ></ Label >

        </ StackLayout >

      </ ContentPage.Content >

    </ ContentPage >

    < ContentPage Title= "Related" >

      < ContentPage.Content >

        < StackLayout Padding= "20, 20, 20, 0" >

          < Label Text= "To Do: Render Related Content Here." ></ Label >

        </ StackLayout >

      </ ContentPage.Content >

    </ ContentPage >

    < ContentPage Title= "Surveys" IsEnabled= "False" >

      < ContentPage.Content >

        < StackLayout Padding= "20" >

          < ListView  x:Name= "surveyList" ItemsSource= "{Binding Surveys}" SelectedItem= "{Binding SelectedSurvey, Mode=TwoWay}" BackgroundColor= "White" HorizontalOptions= "Fill" SeparatorColor= "Gray" RowHeight= "50" >

            < ListView.Header >

              < StackLayout Padding= "0, 0, 0, 10" VerticalOptions= "Center" >

                  < Label Text= "Surveys" FontSize= "20" TextColor= "Gray" LineBreakMode= "NoWrap" />

              </ StackLayout >

            </ ListView.Header >

            < ListView.ItemTemplate >

              < DataTemplate >

                < ViewCell >

                  < ViewCell.View >

                    < StackLayout VerticalOptions= "Center" >

                      < Grid ColumnSpacing= "20" >

                        < Grid.RowDefinitions >

                          < RowDefinition Height= "*" />

                        </ Grid.RowDefinitions >

                        < Grid.ColumnDefinitions >

                          < ColumnDefinition Width= "*" />

                          < ColumnDefinition Width= "50" />

                        </ Grid.ColumnDefinitions >

                        < Label Text= "{Binding HydratedSurvey.Name}" FontSize= "12" TextColor= "Black" FontAttributes= "Bold" Grid.Row= "0" Grid.Column= "0" />

                        < Label Text= "{Binding SurveyInstanceCount}" FontSize= "12" TextColor= "Green" FontAttributes= "Bold" Grid.Row= "0" Grid.Column= "1" />

                      </ Grid >

                    </ StackLayout >

                  </ ViewCell.View >

                </ ViewCell >

              </ DataTemplate >

            </ ListView.ItemTemplate >

          </ ListView >

        </ StackLayout >

      </ ContentPage.Content >

    </ ContentPage >

  </ TabbedPage.Children >

</ TabbedPage >
```

**Code Behind-**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.View
{
    public partial class ModuleContentPage : TabbedPage
    {
        private Page PreviousPage { get; set; }

        public ModuleContentPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // TODO hard coded to disabled the first two tabs and select Surveys. Remove when other tabs are finished
            DisableTab(Children[0]);
            DisableTab(Children[1]);

            //Children[0].IsEnabled = false;
            //Children[1].IsEnabled = false;
            //PreviousPage = Children[2];
            //CurrentPage = PreviousPage;
            CurrentPage = Children[2];

            CurrentPageChanged += ModuleContentPage_CurrentPageChanged;
            PagesChanged += ModuleContentPage_PagesChanged;
        }

        private void DisableTab(Page page)
        {
            page.IsEnabled = false;
            //page.Unfocus();
            page.Opacity = 50.0;
        }

        private void ModuleContentPage_PagesChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentPage = Children[2];
        }

        private void ModuleContentPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentPage = Children[2];
        }
    }
}
```

** View Model-**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MyApp.DataModel.TransferObjects;
using MyApp.DataAccess.UoW;
using MyApp.Services;
using MyApp.SQLiteAccess.Repository;
using MyApp.SQLiteAccess.Tables;
using MyApp.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.ViewModel
{
    public class SurveyListItem : ViewModelBase
    {
        public SurveyDTO HydratedSurvey { get; set; }
        private int _surveyInstanceCount;
        public int SurveyInstanceCount { get { return _surveyInstanceCount; } set { _surveyInstanceCount = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    public class ModuleContentPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ModuleHydratedDTO _module;
        public ModuleHydratedDTO Module { get { return _module; } set { _module = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }

        private ModuleContentHydratedDTO _moduleContent;
        public ModuleContentHydratedDTO ModuleContent { get { return _moduleContent; } set { _moduleContent = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }

        SqlSurveyInstanceRepository _sqlSurveyInstanceRepository;
        SqlSurveyInstanceRepository SqlSurveyInstanceRepository { get { return _sqlSurveyInstanceRepository ?? (_sqlSurveyInstanceRepository = new SqlSurveyInstanceRepository()); } }

        private ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem> _surveys;
        public ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem> Surveys { get { return _surveys; } set { _surveys = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }

        public ModuleContentPageViewModel(ModuleHydratedDTO module, ModuleContentHydratedDTO moduleContent) : base()
        {
            _module = module;
            _moduleContent = moduleContent;
            _surveys = GetSurveys();

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Stores.SurveyStore, SurveyDTO>(this, "UpdateSurveyInstanceCount", (sender, hydratedSurvey) =>
            {
                SurveyListItem survey = _surveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.HydratedSurvey.SurveyId == hydratedSurvey.SurveyId);
                if (survey != null)
                {
                    survey.SurveyInstanceCount = UoW.SurveyInstances.GetCountForSurveyIdAsync(hydratedSurvey.MasterSurveyId ?? hydratedSurvey.SurveyId, ModuleContent.ModuleContentId).Result;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem> GetSurveys()
        {
            ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem> surveyList = new ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem>();
            List<SurveyDTO> surveys = UoW.Surveys.GetHydratedSurveysForUser(_module.Module.ModuleId);

            if (surveys.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var survey in surveys)
                {
                    SurveyListItem item = new SurveyListItem();
                    item.HydratedSurvey = survey;
                    item.SurveyInstanceCount = UoW.SurveyInstances.GetCountForSurveyIdAsync(survey.MasterSurveyId.HasValue ? survey.MasterSurveyId.Value : survey.SurveyId, ModuleContent.ModuleContentId).Result;
                    surveyList.Add(item);
                }
            }
            return surveyList;
        }

        private SurveyListItem _selectedSurvey;
        public SurveyListItem SelectedSurvey
        {
            get { return _selectedSurvey; }
            set
            {
                _selectedSurvey = value;
                if (_selectedSurvey == null)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    return;
                }
                OnSurveySelected(_selectedSurvey);
                _selectedSurvey = null;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void OnSurveySelected(SurveyListItem selectedSurvey)
        {
            NavigationService.PushAsync(new SurveyInstanceListVM(selectedSurvey.HydratedSurvey, _moduleContent.ModuleContentId), selectedSurvey.HydratedSurvey.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

**Edit Edit-**

Here is the frankenstiened viewmodel/viewmodelbase combination.

```
using MyApp.DataModel.TransferObjects;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using MyApp.ViewModelFramework.Spooling;

namespace MyApp.ViewModel
{
    public class SurveyListItem
    {
        public string Name { get { return "foo"; } set { var x = value; } }
        private int _surveyInstanceCount;
        public int SurveyInstanceCount { get { return _surveyInstanceCount; } set { _surveyInstanceCount = value; } }
    }

    public class ModuleContentPageViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem> _surveys;
        public ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem> Surveys { get { return _surveys; } set { _surveys = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }


        public ModuleContentPageViewModel(ModuleHydratedDTO module, ModuleContentHydratedDTO moduleContent) : base()
        {
            _surveys = GetSurveys();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem> GetSurveys()
        {
            ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem> surveyList = new ObservableCollection<SurveyListItem>();
            surveyList.Add(new SurveyListItem());
            return surveyList;
        }

        private SurveyListItem _selectedSurvey;
        public SurveyListItem SelectedSurvey
        {
            get { return _selectedSurvey; }
            set
            {
                _selectedSurvey = value;
                if (_selectedSurvey == null)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    return;
                }
                _selectedSurvey = null;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            InvokeNotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public NotifyPropertyChangedSpooler NotificationSpooler = new NotifyPropertyChangedSpooler();

        private NotificationPropertyChangedStateEnum _notificationPropertyChangedState = NotificationPropertyChangedStateEnum.Active;

        // Gets and sets change notification spooling and blocking features.
        public NotificationPropertyChangedStateEnum NotificationPropertyChangedState
        {
            get { return _notificationPropertyChangedState; }
            set
            {
                _notificationPropertyChangedState = value;
                if (_notificationPropertyChangedState == NotificationPropertyChangedStateEnum.Active && !NotificationSpooler.IsEmpty)
                {
                    NotificationSpooler.Unwind();
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

            }
        }


        void InvokeNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            switch (NotificationPropertyChangedState)
            {
                case NotificationPropertyChangedStateEnum.Active:
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    break;
                case NotificationPropertyChangedStateEnum.Spooling:
                    NotificationSpooler.Enqueue(this, propertyName);
                    break;
                case NotificationPropertyChangedStateEnum.Inactive:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public enum NotificationPropertyChangedStateEnum
    {
        Inactive = 0,
        Active = 1,
        Spooling = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you define your list? Is it just a list or ObservableCollection? More code and xaml will help. Ideally if you could post complete code for that page and code behind including model we might help faster

Comment: It is an ObservableCollection. I've updated with the page xaml, code behind, and view model

Comment: Going to try... Are you testing on device or simulator? What iOS version?

Comment: I am testing on an iPad mini that is 9.x something, and an iPhone emulator that is the latest version (10.x something). I updated everything this week. There was never a point where we knew this was working because we've been doing all of our development on android, this is the first time we're trying ios (whoops)

Comment: I found that building for iOS 10 creates some problems. Can you try to build it for iOS9?

Comment: Just confirmed, it is 9.3.5 and the emulator is 10.1. Unfortunately, 9.3.5 is not firing the setter as well :\- Also if you help me resolve it in the comments please make it an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Missing ViewModelBase and SurveyDTO and SurveyInstanceListVM

Comment: I think that's as far as I can go. ViewModelBase is doing a lot of IoC stuff so at some point you'l need 80% of the app to use my example verbatim. It's horribly coupled

Comment: I can try to strip your code to what I really need but it might take some time. For example all SQL stuff. Can you strip the code fast?

Comment: I'll give that a shot- one minute

Comment: I need at list SurveyDTO and BAseViewmodel as it implements some propchanged notifications

Comment: Check my update. Does that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128490/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-micah-williamson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation was found that the page was disabled in xaml and never enabled neither in xaml nor in code behind. For some reason it wasn't problem in Android (which is kind of wrong and should be investigated more why).

Comment: Thank you, Yuri, for spending so much time looking into this and helping us resolve this! - If I could give this guy more than 1+ I would :)

Comment: @MicahWilliamson My pleasure